# presentar un select para generar un comando en SQL que redondee a dos dígitos (si solo tiene uno),

Tags: sql-server

Distrito Área    (km2) original       Área (km2) redondeado
Curridabat            6,17                  06,17
Granadilla            3,51                  03,51
Sánchez               4,51                  04,51
Tirrases              1,88                  01,88

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tu problema no parece ser para redondear sino para agregar ceros. Eso se debe de realizar en la capa de presentación y no en la consulta.